# unicode_escape without deprecation warning

Tags: python

In Python 3.8, the following:

```py
import codecs

codecs.decode("hello\\,world", "unicode_escape")
```

...produces a deprecation warning:

```
<ipython-input-7-28f185d30178>:1: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence '\,'
  codecs.decode("hello\\,", "unicode_escape", errors="strict")
```

1. Is this going to become an error in a future version of Python? Where is the reference for this?
2. If No, is there a way to not display this warning, if Yes, what can I use instead?

**Edit:** I am (obviously) not interested in fixing this for a string I would have written literally in my Python script. This is purely an example, in my use case strings come from external files, I cannot change them, and some contains invalid escape sequences such as this.

Comment: Python 3 strings are Unicode so no escaping is needed. `h` is no less a Unicode character than Ω

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't really see how this is related to my question... I'm reading the string from a file and I would like to convert `hello\,world` to a Python string containing `"hello\\,world"` or `"hello,world"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've got two layers of de-escaping occurring here. The first one is the regular string literal escaping, converting `"hello\\,world"` to a string with raw characters of `hello\,world`. Then `codecs.decode` tries to decode it with `unicode_escape`, which sees it as an attempt to escape `,` with `\`, which is an invalid escape.

The fix for your code as written is to use a raw string so the first level of escaping doesn't happen:

```
codecs.decode(r"hello\\,world", "unicode_escape")
            # ^ Now it's a raw string, and both backslashes are in fact backslashes
```

If your data comes from elsewhere with invalid escapes, you can suppress the warning for now (see the `warnings` module for details), but it will eventually cause an exception in a future version of Python, so the long term solution is "Don't provide invalid data". Sorry that's not super-helpful.

The reason you get this warning is that, historically, Python has been kind of lax about spurious escapes. So if you wrote, say, a Windows path of `"C:\yes"` it said "hey, `\y` doesn't mean anything, so we'll just assume they wanted a literal backslash", while an equivalent path of `"C:\no"` saw `\n` and thought "Yup, they want a newline there".

This taught bad habits (not using raw strings when you should, because it usually worked without them) and created confusion when those habits bit you (why isn't it working *this* time!?!). So in the future, escapes like `\y` will be treated as errors, so that you end up writing `r'C:\yes'` and are used to doing so so you don't get bit by `r'C:\no'`. The warning is reminding you that this is bad code, and will eventually stop working (for good reason; as your own comment notes, you're okay with it ending up with either no backslashes or two backslashes, starting with just one, which is an insane set of options to accept without *knowing* the single, correct, desired result).

---

### Alternative solution

If your goal is to "fix" bad strings, the best solution is probably to just write your own simple stripping regex, e.g.:

```
import re

bad_escape_re = re.compile(r'\\(?=[^\n\\\'"abfnrtv0-7xNuU])')
```

and then use it to strip unrecognized escapes a la:

```
good_string = bad_escape_re.sub('', bad_string)
```

which when run like so:

```
bad_escape_re.sub('', r'\a\b\c\d\e\f\g\,\.\n\t\x12')
```

produces a string with the `repr` `'\\a\\bcde\\fg,.\\n\\t\\x12'`. Note that's it's not perfect, and if you need it to validate the extended escapes to distinguish valid uses from invalid ones (`\[0-7]`, `\x`, `\N`, `\u` and `\U`), it gets more complicated, but those are also cases where it's invariably heuristic and there is no good solution; without a human to interpret, `\xab` is legal and `\xag` is not, but it's entirely likely the former wasn't intended as an escape either.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am on the second use-case (invalid data provided by external source). Is there a method (even in a 3rd party lib) that can be used to do this? Or to remove the invalid `\\`?

Comment: @Holt: I mean, you could just write a regex that finds a backslash followed by an unrecognized escape character, and use `re.sub` to remove the backslash. It's ugly, but when you're parsing bad data, ugly is kind of a given. `re.sub(r'\\(?=[^abfnrtuUx0-9])', r'', mystring)` or something to that effect.

Comment: I definitely left off some characters in there, but you can get the complete list of recognized escapes [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) and expand the inverted character class to cover all of them.

Comment: Thanks, could you add this to your answer? This is more what I was looking for.

Comment: @Holt: Added it to the end as an alternative solution, and included a note about this really being a heuristic. For bad inputs, there's really no way (without human intervention and interpretation) to know that `"C:\no"` wasn't intended to be an escape (though to a human it clearly was); it could have been backslashing characters at random, only some of which were escapes.

Comment: There is an issue with the regex for escape backslashes, it replaces two backslashes with a single one, and I can't find a way to fix it...

Comment: A look-behind fixed it `re.compile(r"(^|(?<=[^\\]))\\(?=[^abfnrtuUx0-9\\])")`. I understand this is very heuristic, this comes from a custom script language that has been used for a decade now so I cannot really rewrite all the existing scripts (even if I wanted, I could not redistribute them), so I'll just try to match the behavior of existing parsers.

Comment: @Holt: It does? I see `bad_escape_re.sub('', r'\\')` produce a repr of `'\\\\'`, which is exactly as many backslashes as the original. Edit: Ah, glad you found a solution.

Comment: Hmm... `r'\\'` actually works, `r'\\v'` also works but `r'\\V'` produces a repr of `\\V`. **Edit:** Ok, my bad, `v` is actually a valid escape character after `\` which is why it kinds of work for `v`, but not for `V`.